# Does the unsemantic framework eliminate the need for media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-frameworks, grid-system, unsemantic-css

The unsemantic css framwork snaps web layouts to mobile and desktop modes depending on the viewport size. You can also heavily modify what appears on the desktop vs mobile using 'show-on-desktop' and 'show-on-mobile' classes, which do exactly what they say.

Does this mean I can say goodbye to media queries?

http://unsemantic.com/

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

In actuality, **Unsemantic** abstracts away the use of @media queries in one of two ways:

1. Providing responsive CSS versions (unsemantic-grid-responsive.css or unsemantic-grid-responsive-tablet.css) that create these @media queries for you according to predefined breakpoints.
2. Loading an individual CSS file without @media queries, after determining the viewport size on load using **Adapt.js**; then, optionally loading additional CSS files if necessary according to customizable breakpoints upon resizing the viewport.

Source: http://unsemantic.com/css-documentation